# Overriding public static const members in child classes

Tags: c++, static, overriding, parent-child, public

I have a piece of working code that I am not sure about. See below for a mocked up version. The jist of it is I have a `Foo` class, a `ChildFoo` class and `Bar` class which has an instance of `Foo`. `Foo` presents some keys to `Bar` to parse a json dictionary. `Bar` is generic and used in multiple ways, `Foo` is subclassed for each implementation.

I have a `public static const std::string` in `Foo`, which defaults to `""` in which case the `Bar` method to parse the value out just uses its own name instead of a specific key. I override `PARAM_VALUE` in `ChildFoo` because it's json dictionary is more complicated and provides `{value: [], type:[], ...}`, whereas other implementations just return `{mName: []}`.

Foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static const std::string PARAM_VALUE;
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
const std::string Foo::PARAM_VALUE = "";

Foo::Foo ()
{
...
}
```

ChildFoo.cpp:

```
const std::string Foo::PARAM_VALUE = "value";

ChildFoo::ChildFoo() : Foo()
{
...
}
```

Bar.h

```
class Bar
{
private:
    std::string mName;
    ChildFoo * mFoo;
}
```

Bar.cpp:

```
Bar::Bar ()
{
...
}

int Bar::parseValue ()
{
    std::string key;
    if (!mFoo->PARAM_VALUE.empty()) {
        key = mFoo->PARAM_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        key = mName;
    }
    ...
}
```

I assumed I would have to go down the route of virtual getters for these keys, but thought I would try this out and was slightly surprised to find it works. On thinking about it, I believe it works because `Foo::PARAM_VALUE` is overridden by `ChildFoo` at compile time, so the `const` isn't restrictive at that point. I'm not completely sure, though.

Is it unsurprising that this works? Is this considered OK? Are there any drawbacks that could come from doing things in this way?

Cheers,
Gary

Comment: Does it link ? You have multiple (different) definitions of `const std::string Foo::PARAM_VALUE` -> ODR violation.

Comment: It compiles and runs as I would like it to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that your linker would allow this, the behaviour is certainly undefined if it does.

Your code is in violation of the *one definition rule*.

You can resort to *variable shadowing* if you want, but bear in mind that this would not be polymorphic. If you want polymorphism, then you'd need to use virtual functions.

Comment: Is it possible different compilers would complain about this? I am using gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18).

Comment: Formally it's the link stage that ought to issue a complaint.